# The text color does not change TabWidget

Tags: android, android-tabhost, textview, android-textattributes

I'm trying to change the `TabWidget` text color, without success, even though I've tried different way to change it (see code below.)

My background tabs is an image:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
}
```

I do not know if this creates some sort of conflict with what I want to do now.

**Solution1:**

main.xml

```
....
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tabbarbackground"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false"            
        style="@style/TabText"
        /> ....
```

style.xml

```
... <style name="TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_text_color</item> </style> ....
```

tab_text_color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:textColor="#2daed9" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</selector>
```

---

**solution 2**

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);         
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(1);
    textView.setTextColor(R.color.tab_text_color);
}
```

tab_text_color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:textColor="#2daed9" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="#FFFFFF" /> </selector>
```

but neither solution works.

However, if I change the second solution

```
textView.setTextColor (R.color.tab_text_color);
```

to

```
textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("# ...."));
```

It works, except this solution does not change the color of text when I click on it.

Thanks.

Comment: see here for better solution of how to change the text color.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982182/using-selector-to-change-textview-text-color/15498013#15498013!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve, the solution isn't elegant but works. I hope who is usefull for somebody:

First, I must set init color for the textview of all tabs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
    vg = (ViewGroup) getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    tv = (TextView) vg.getChildAt(1);
    tv.setTypeface(font);
    if (i == 0) {
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2daed9"));
        Currentab = 0;
    } else {
        tv.setTextColor(R.color.GrisOscuro);
    }
}
```

And then, I  set in the override method ontabchanged, the change color for each tab. The tab pulsed are i (getTabHost().getCurrentTab()).  And the last tab who I press is Currentab.

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int i = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
        if (Currentab != i) {
            vg = (ViewGroup) getTabHost().getTabWidget()
                    .getChildAt(Currentab);
            tv = (TextView) vg.getChildAt(1);
            tv.setTextColor(R.color.GrisOscuro);

            Currentab = i;
            vg = (ViewGroup) getTabHost().getTabWidget()
                    .getChildAt(i);
            tv = (TextView) vg.getChildAt(1);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2daed9"));
        }
    }
});
```

Sorry for my english, I hope is useful for somebody =) Bye! ;D

Answer (score 4):

In your **solution 2**:

```
TabWidget tabwidget=mTabHost.getTabWidget();
for(int i=0;i<tabwidget.getChildCount();i++){
    TextView tv=(TextView) tabwidget.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_text_xml));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to write this methode:

```
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
{
TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget()
.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.your_text_id);
    tv.setTextColor(#FFFFFF);
```

}

```
TextView tv = (TextView)    tabHost.getTabWidget().
getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).findViewById(R.id.your_text_id);

tv.setTextColor(#2daed9);
}
```

Comment: thanks but  won't worked for my, because I  use a tabwidget without textview and imageview on xml...  I  try do something similar but  I can't because i cant access an concrete tab only if I do with a for:

for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(1);//          
     textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
}