# TextView color is not changing on click

Tags: java, android, colors, textview

I'm using selector to change textview color when user touch it. But the color is permanently black and not changing when touch. Here is my code :

@color/red.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:color="#000000" />
```

textview :

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="59dp"
    android:layout_y="449dp"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Solution : Use setOnClickListener() for textview instead of setOnTouchListener().

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9982308/2065418

Comment: I am not sure if it is relevant but you can try to set android:clickable="true" it may somehow solve your issue, because your selector seems ok to me...

Comment: Thanks.but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/color_white" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/color_black"></item>
```

in color.xml

```
<drawable name="color_black">#000000</drawable>
<drawable name="color_white">#ffffff</drawable>
```

Comment: did you do this ===>textview.setOnClickListener() and textView.setClickable(true)

Comment: I used textview.setOnTouchListener()

Comment: hi @Vinoch i edited my answer if previous not work try above.

Comment: onTouch will not work you hava to do OnClick Listener if you want to use selecter.

Comment: can we use onclickListener for textview?? I thought we should use ontouchlistner().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41948/discussion-between-hardik-and-vinoch)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
<item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

Comment: No effect,it still remains black..am i wrong with my textview coding??

Comment: Make sure you have red.xml in drawable folders and use @drawable/red instead of android:textColor="@color/red"

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this may be this is helpful

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#000000" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
<item android:color="#000000" />
```

Comment: If you want to Give answer then post this to as a Answer...not as a comment..!!

Comment: i am facing problem in pasting the code in comments thats why i am commenting