# How change the color of selected Textview

Tags: android

I have lots of textview in screen. I want to change color of textview whenever user click it and color should be remained same until user click other textview.

For this i am used this slector but it isn't working like that.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" android:color="#000"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#12fdfd"/>
</selector>
```

How should i do it? any help

[image]

Comment: have you set clickable=true inside textview

Comment: are you talking about contextclickable?

Comment: i mean android:clickable="true" property of textview

Comment: yes i have that property enabled but still it doesn't work.

Comment: See this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982182/using-selector-to-change-textview-text-color

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView` need to implemented [Checkable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html) interface. Try to use Known Indirect Subclasses of [Checkable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html) eg. `CheckedTextView` or implement your own `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **TextView** by **CheckedTextView** then your selector must be as following

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item  android:state_checked="true"   android:color="#12fdfd"/>
     <item  android:color="#000"/>
  </selector>
```

use the ***setChecked(boolean bln)*** function for your CheckedTextView

```
 mCTxtView.setChecked(true);
```

You can use it as checkbox ui by setting drawable for checkedTextView

android:drawableLeft="@drawable/radio_drawable"

> radio_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_checked"  android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Comment: would there be a checkbox in ui with checkedTextView?

Comment: Yes you can by setting drawable

Comment: once mCTxtView.setChecked(true); is set then it will remain true whole time. how would i make it false when other textview would be clicked so only one textview should be checked at a one one

Comment: you must implement       mCTxtView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { } 
to set others unchecked 
do you use RecyclerView or ListView ?

Comment: that would make my code so long if i go like this. There could be hunderd of static textviews

Comment: No It wouldn't if you use RecyclerView or ListView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106785/discussion-between-zeeshan-shabbir-and-ahmed-khamis).